# Should Password fields retain their values if a form does not pass validation?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, passwords, validation

I have a typical sign-up form with two password fields.

```
<form>
    <%= Html.TextBox("Email", null) %>

    <%= Html.Password("password", null) %>
    <%= Html.Password("confirmPassword", null) %>

    <input type='submit' />
</form>
```

If the form fails validation and is redisplayed, the text field retains its value but the password fields are always blank.

**Why shouldn't the password fields retain their values?**  And more importantly, is there any reason I shouldn't override this behavior?

I feel like this behavior decreases usability, and would prefer password fields to behave the same way as textbox fields -- keeping the entered value when validation errors exist.

I'm using ASP.NET MVC, but this question pertains more to usability and security. I understand that what I'm seeing is expected behavior, and taking a look at the `Password(...)` method shows me that it explicitly ignores the value in `ModelState`.

Comment: How do you think those passwords are transmitted over the wire? Are they encrypted?

Comment: This particular example is secured using HTTPS; however, even if this was HTTP, the passwords would be POST'ed in plain text, so I don't see a problem with returning them in the HTML.

Comment: This isn't just an MVC specific thing. It seems to be common practice all over the web. Anytime you go through some registration form but make some mistake, when the form gets presented back to you, your password is gone. I guess you do have a valid question there as to WHY that is...

Comment: @BFree Exactly!  It's not specific to MVC at all ... I see it all over the place.  But I must know WHY!  Because as far as I can tell, it's just a bad practice.

Comment: +1 Very interesting. I get annoyed from retyping passwords when registration fails.

Comment: I wonder if it's a security practice. I suppose it would be possible that the page returned with the populated password fields could be cached on the client and someone snooping around the local cache could discover the passwords.

Comment: @GWB: Interesting, caching.  Possible answer!

Comment: @Platinum Azure The type of textbox does not change the encryption

Comment: @Oskar Kjellin: I'm aware of that. I was trying to draw attention to that fact with a rhetorical question.

Comment: @Platinum Azure Well, OK. You could still just listen to the outbound traffic if your would like, not sending it to the inbound does not decrease the ability to listen to the traffic

Comment: I think the idea is that if it was wrong the first time, why retain it? Of course in the scenario where you do know your password and know that you just mistyped a character - and you know which one - then yes it's convenient to retain the value. When that's not the case, you just have a bunch of (probably) masked characters that you now have to delete before trying again - not so convenient.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answers submitted by @NickHeidke and @Chris Lively were both great and led me to a few conclusions that I would like to share.

First of all, regarding usability: the ONLY place where it might be appropriate for a password field to retain its value is on a "sign-up" form, when the form does not pass validation, and the validation issue is NOT related to the password or confirm password.  It is definitely not appropriate for a "log-in" form, "change password" form, or probably any other place.  Therefore, the fact that `Html.Password` ignores the `ModelState` makes perfect sense.

Second, regarding security: unless carefully implemented, a "sign-up" form will be saved in your browser's navigation history. Pressing "Back" will resend your password, which would probably fail validation, and return the form with your password filled out.  The fact that the password is filled out is NOT a security breach though, because its the same password that the browser already saved and sent.  You can "View Source" to see the password, but you could view the page request to see the password too (for example, using FireBug).

Granted, it is easier and more obvious to "View Source" when you see a password filled out, but I'd say the better solution is implementing the "sign-up" form in a way that isn't saved to browser history; for example, the [PRG Pattern with a Validation workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538005/post-redirect-get-in-asp-net-mvc-and-validation-with-restful-urls), but that is a whole different topic!

**My conclusion is this**: password fields should almost always be clear when shown.
If you want to increase usability and don't want to make users retype their passwords, try to use **client-side validation** first!
And finally, if you really know what you're doing, and really want to increase usability, it's ok to persist the values on a sign-up form.  But it probably isn't the best idea.

Comment: Yes. You can fill the password if failed validation is not related to it. Specially in cases where you have accept something checkboxes, captchas, document validators, etc. As you concluded, while there is no security flaw, it's better to default to blank because general use cases. Note aside: Client-side validation is an 'easy' way to manage the scenario that also improves usability but it's not directly related to the fill thing. Behavior doesn't only applies to passwords, captcha is also a great candidate. Resetting captcha after a password confirm error, it is simple the same pain.

Comment: Possible improvement to this design would be to move the password fields to a subsequent screen which only included the passwords.  That way you can do back-end validation on all the sign-up fields and then let the user deal with the password in isolation.

Answer (score 16):

You can send the value back on a regular input type=password field.

However, if you are using the .net input control, then it will clear the contents of value prior to sending the html back to the client.

The reason is simple: They wanted to limit the number of times in which a password was sent back and forth between the server and the browser.  This helps limit exposure to some systems.([link](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.aspnet/browse_thread/thread/22579917fae1ca3f/ff9f3be06c4f0396?lnk=st&q=password%20field%20cleared%20on%20postback&rnum=2#ff9f3be06c4f0396))

Now, obviously, if you are using ssl then this isn't much of a consideration.  Unforunately the vast majority of sites out there STILL don't use SSL and will happily send data back and forth in the clear.  The more times that field travels between client and server, the more opportunities someone has of grabbing it ala FireSheep.

Bear in mind, this isn't to say that someone listening in on the whole conversation won't get it from the first post.  However, consider it like a simple option to limit (not eliminate) the attack surface.

The next reason is that nearly every time sites show the password field to the user after a submit, it's because validation didn't pass.  This could mean that the username and/or password is incorrect.  Considering that password fields only display asterisks or dots to the user, there's no real reason to give it back to them.

Given that you never want to tell the user which of the credentials failed (ie: you do NOT want to say "password invalid" or "username invalid") AND that common users have no way of figuring out whether they fat fingered their entry, it's much better IMHO to clear BOTH.

---

All of that aside, you have a choice here.  The standard is to blank it.  Considering that this is the way the vast majority of sites work, do you really want to go against the grain?  Personally, I find that we are much better off sticking to UI standards even when we disagree with them.

Users already have a hard enough time with all the different options available.

Comment: Thank you for your well-thought-out answer. However, I disagree that "limiting the attack surface" increases security. If you have a HTTP site, your usernames and passwords are sent in the clear, and reducing that traffic by < 50% won't help you much.  Your second point is true, but it assumes a "log in" page, not a "sign up" page, which should definitely be treated differently.  Finally, I disagree that there is a "standard" ... case in point, StackOverflow keeps your password intact if you fail CAPTCHA!

Comment: @Scott: I agree, it wouldn't help much.  However, that was the thinking behind it which, I believe, was what you were asking for... ;)  Going back to the signup page, I again believe they should BOTH be cleared.  How would the user possibly know which one was wrong if it errors out because the passwords don't match?  They wouldn't, so to be kind to your users you clear them and ask them to try again.  Which, from a usability point of view is much nicer than being faced with 2 boxes filled with dots and not knowing which to clear.  Faced with that the user is going to clear both and try again.

Comment: @Scott: BTW, a single site that does something differently than the de facto standard isn't much of an argument that said standard doesn't exist.  In fact, looking at SO, all your user credentials and everything else is passed in the clear and they've publicly stated that security isn't a priority here... So if your after an honestly secure system, I wouldn't take those lessons from how SO does things.

Answer (score 3):

The explanation I've heard for this in the past, is that if a user clicks submit and walks away from their computer, someone else shouldn't be able to come along and re-submit without their knowledge.

Comment: Seems pretty far fetched to me. The evil user still won't get the password easily, he just can change the password (then why would he do that?)

Comment: @Oskar: if you would retain the (correct) password after validation fails or even after postbacks, you would have a big security hole. As Nick mentioned people could login and do whatever they want to do(online-banking etc.). This problem would even occur if the user has left the page but the next user clicks the back-button in browser as long as he gets to your filled assword-field.

Comment: In order to override the default browser behavior you have to use the value property, this means that if you view the source, you would see the password.  Browsers by default will not retain password fields.

Comment: @Tim It is a good reason not to change this behaviour due to the fact that people can press back and get the password, but that is not what he wrote

Comment: This is a good point. If a website is poorly implemented, a "failed signup" page could be retained in history, and then the Evil user could use the Back button + "view source" to see the password. However, in this scenario, the security hole is that the **browser** is remembering the submitted password and re-posting it.  An Evil user could use methods other than "view source" to see the browser's POST (for example, FireBug). I believe the PRG pattern is the best bet to prevent the browser from re-posting passwords.

Comment: @Scott Then the evil browser probably remember the incorrect password (if the username wasn't invalid, which is less likely)

Comment: @Oskar The Evil browser remembered both password and confirmPassword, one of which is probably right.

Comment: @Scott True, I was thinking of login page

Answer (score 3):

Answer given by @Scott Rippey, really explains a lot. 
You cannot retain the value of @Html.Password or @Html.PasswordFor because it is hardcoded in the helper itself. for more refer to this link.
[retain password value.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21794016/retain-the-password-text-box-values-after-submit-in-mvc#_=_)

Solution:
What you can do, is replace the Password or PasswordFor box with,

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Password, new { type = "password" })
```

Answer (score 0):

While I agree that when logging on this behaviour is sensible, it feel it provides an extremely poor user experience when say, creating a user account. When there are many fields on a form and the user makes a mistake in one or more fields, having to re-enter the passwords (new and confirm) is very very annoying, and when the password fields are not visible in view without scrolling it is very easy to forget to re-enter them.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the reason for the question.  "I feel like this behavior decreases usability, and would prefer password fields to behave the same way as textbox fields -- keeping the entered value when validation errors exist."

Comment: From @ScottRippey answer: _the ONLY place where it might be appropriate for a password field to retain its value is on a "sign-up" form, when the form does not pass validation, and the validation issue is NOT related to the password or confirm password._